# Best way to disable default Azure proxy on on-prem hosts

Tags: azure

I was recently doing some work on some servers, and had issues with outbound connectivity.  I tracked down the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/proxy.conf` which contained the line `DefaultEnvironment="https_proxy=http://100.79.11.37:8080"` - this had the effect of making all https calls made by all systemd units go out via this proxy, which was the cause of the issues.  I'm told this is part of a set of tools to make on-prem servers behave like Azure servers.

Once found I was able to work around it easily by putting a line `Environment=no_proxy=*` in my own service definition files.

For future peoples sake (internet searches turned up nothing for "100.79.11.37 8080" at the time) and out of curiosity, how are other people dealing with this?

- Overriding in each service file separately like me?
- Putting in another custom conf (with potentially more sophisticated rules)?
- Just removing that bundled conf file entirely?
- Something better?

Comment: If these are on-prem servers, so not running in Azure, where is the proxy setting coming from in the first  place?

Comment: I believe it's installed as part of the ADC suite, which is a tool Microsoft distribute for connecting on-prem services to Azure.